# Error installing Homebrew: /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 46

Tags: bash, terminal, homebrew, sudo

I am trying to install Homebrew (using the code snippet right off their site):

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I am getting:

```
 >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 46 <<<
    sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 46
    sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Not great with terminal commands and lingo. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `/etc/sudoers` file seems to be borked, probably because you edited it before. Most likely not Homebrew's fault, but a pre-existing condition. Edit the file, paying attention to like 46, and see if you can fix it. If not, post the contents of the file (anonymised, if necessary). EDIT: be careful, messing up your sudoers file is kind of dangerous. Maybe post the file first.

Comment: @Amadan thanks! I have no idea what i'm doing so this helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/sudoers file seems to be borked.
Never open sudoer file with a normal editor. always use visudo

just type

```
sudo visudo
```

this will take you to `/etc/sudoers` and upon saving it will make sure that there is no error in formatting.

if you make an error in sudoer file, you will lose sudo access, so always use `visudo`